# OpenLayers 3 - how to redraw a single feature

Tags: openlayers, rendering

I would like to be able to trigger re-rendering of a single feature after a user has clicked on it. (I can catch the click and update the metadata that feeds the styling function, but I am then forced to re-render the entire layer to get the updated styling to show:

```
kmlSource.dispatchChangeEvent();
```

Performance is horrible redrawing a an entire large layer when just one feature's style has changed. Is there any way I can redraw just one feature?

Even if the rendering wasn't perfect (for example the redrawn feature was on top) that would be fine.

I note this [older question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/openlayers-canvas-renderer-redraws-all-features-on-selecting-a-single-feature) on the previous version of openlayers, but I can't find anything addressing the issue on OpenLayers 3.

Comment: The question you refer to on OpenLayers 2. Is your question about OpenLayers 2 or OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of things I'd suggest trying the `changed()` function on the feature after updating the styling. This seems to work when I updated the scale of the style for a feature. See the feature [changed documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html?unstable=true#changed)

Answer (score 1):

Your use case should be covered by `ol.interaction.Select`. For drawing the selected feature with a different style, `ol.interaction.Select` creates an `ol.FeatureOverlay` with your alternate style and adds your feature to that overlay. To hide the original feature while displaying your feature on the overlay, it uses the internal `ol.Map#skipFeature()` method to skip the selected feature when replaying the render sequence on the original layer.

Comment: ahocevar, `ol.Map#skipFeature` isn't currently part of the API. But it should probably be.

Comment: erilem, I'll refine my answer. I am not so sure that `ol.Map#skipFeature` should be part of the API. I just thought it was.